# react-native http request with Hindi word in url not working

Tags: react-native

This code is run in react-native, I am unable to get the correct response.

```js
let url =
  'https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=hi&tl=en&dt=t&q=नमस्ते';

fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: null,
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    console.log('responseJson: ', responseJson);
    // response: [[["¥ ¥ ¥ à¤¤à ¥ ‡","à¤¨à¤®à¤¸à¥ à¤¤à¥‡",null,null,3]],null,"hi"]
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

I was also used encodeURI to convert the URL, not work for me.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Please change ':' to '=' in the first line !!

```
let url =  "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=hi&tl=en&dt=t&q=नमस्ते"
```

Comment: Yes, i made the solution of it.

In react-native http fetch request, where i need to make request in charset-UTF8 but not find any solution for it.

Finally i find solution where i add a web-view in the react-native app and inject fetch request code in it, i get the response correct. Read back the response from web-view.